# Modeling database relations

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-modeling

I think the best way to describe the problem is by using an example. I will keep it as simple as possible by removing unneeded details of the implementation.

Say there is a book store. The store keeps track of all *books*, *customers*, and *orders* using a backend database to store all the data, and a Java front-end to present them to the manager of the store.

The database contains the following relations:

> 1. **Book** ( *id*, *title*, *author* )
> 2. **Customer** ( *id*, *name*, *tel*, *address* )
> 3. **Order** ( *id*, *date*, *custId*, *bookId* )

On the other side, the Java interface uses [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) driver to connect to the database and retrieve the data. The application consists of the following classes:

> Book
>   BooksDataLoader
>   BooksTableModel
>   BooksView
>
> Customer
>   CustomersDataLoader
>   CustomersTableModel
>   CustomersView
>
> Order
>   OrdersDataLoader
>   OrdersTalbeModel
>   OrdersView

These classes use respective design guidelines and you can use the following source code as reference:

```
public class Book {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    /*
     * Builder pattern is used so constructor should be hidden. Book objects
     * are built in the BooksDataLoader SwingWorker thread.
     */
    private Book() {}
}

public class BooksDataLoader extends SwingWorker<List<Book>, Book> {
    private final BooksTableModel booksModel;
    private final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
}

public class BooksTableModel extend AbstractTableModel {
    private final String columnNames = { "Book ID", "Book Title", "Book Author" };
    private final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
}

public class BooksView extends JPanel {
    private final JTable booksTable;
    private final BooksTableModel booksModel;
}
```

I am using the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to implement the classes Book, Customer, and Order. The instances of these classes are built using data retrieved by the database inside a SwingWorker thread and are published to the view using an AbstractTableModel. So, actually the application consists of the following views (JPanels): BooksView, CustomersView, and OrdersView, each of which contains a single JTable with columns as shown below:

> **BooksView.booksTable**: *Book ID* | *Book Title* | *Book Author*
>
> **CustomersView.customersTable**: *Customer ID* | *Customer Name*
>
> **OrdersView.ordersTable**: *Order ID* | *Date* | *Customer Name* | *Book Title* | *Book Author*

The problem appears when we try to resolve an instance variable which represents a foreign key in the database, to the data it links. For example, the OrdersTableModel has a List structure of all Order objects found in the database, however the columns 3, 4, and 5 of the of the OrdersView table cannot be directly accessed from an Order object since it only contains ids for the book and the customer, and not the actual data. One solution I tried was to create a static HashMap inside each of the Book, Customer, and Order classes in order to keep track of all retrieved objects but it leads to data duplication since we already have a List structure of the retrieved objects in the table model of each view.

I am looking for an efficient and extensible (object-oriented) design solution/recommendation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use ORM like Hibernate or EclipseLink or whatever technology fits you. Currently JPA2 is the common standard implemented by every such tool. You define the mapping between your object and db model by using annotations or xml files.

These tools also offer ways to generate your database schema according to your object model (even the other way is possible if you have legacy schemes).

I recommend you not to make use of jpa criteria api since its design is quite flawed. There are a number of frameworks out there that help you build your queries. QueryDSL is one that seems really nice to me. I used the specification pattern (which I actually implemented using criteria api under the hood) for abstracting query construction. See http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf and http://adrianhummel.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/composed-specifications-using-jpa-2-0/ for first references.

And do some search on DAO pattern and repositories (a term coming from domain driven design).

Comment: I will consider using Hibernate however I am still looking for a native solution (no external packages).

Comment: Why would you try to not include external packages? Does the customer require you to use only java.* imports? What are your requirements? JPA is an acknowledged industry standard and allows you to program against interfaces. The native solution is jdbc and that requires a lot of coding. You should consider designing a thin persistence abstraction layer with any technology such that your application does not have too many dependencies to external classes/interfaces. But I do not recommend to use jdbc as your level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a typical issue when mapping OO design on relational database tables.

Let's take as example your OrdersTableModel:

Order ID | Date | Customer Name | Book Title | Book Author

the last three columns are database foreign key ids instead of the values you want to show.

To manage this correctly you have 2 possible solution:

FIRST: 
desgin the Order class like this

```
 public class Order{
private String id;
private Date date;
private Customer customer;
private Book book;
private Author author;

get and set methods
}
```

Note that customer is of type CUSTOMER, book of type BOOK...

Now suppose you query the db to retreive a list of orders.
From the rows returned you have to build a list of Objects Order. Of course the db return foreign key ids for customer, book and author so:

1. Query table orders of db
2. For each row build and Orders object, fill id and date with the values of the rows
3. Take the foreign key id for customer. Build a new query on customer db table and take the right customer based on the id. Build a new Customer id filling its values whit the results of this second query. Assign the Customer object to the field customer of the object Orders
4. Same for Book and author
5. Add the object Order to a list

Now you have a list of suppose 10 orders

Iterate on it and fill the order table you display.
To display for example Customer field you will have

```
listOrders[i].getCustomer().getName(). // listOrders[i] is an Order object. getCusotmer returns a customer object. getName is a Customer's method that return the String name.
```

Same for book and Author

SECOND APPROACH

design Order Class like this:

```
  public class Order{
private String id;
private Date date;
private int customer;
private int book;
private int author;

get and set methods
}
```

Note now the customer etc are INT fields. The hold the int reference key retreived from db

Again you query table orders.

For each row build an Order object. Fill the customer etc. values simply with the id of the db.

Now you want to display a list of orders.

Iterate on the list.
when displayng customer use

```
listOrders[i].getCustomer().getName().
```

NOTE as customer field is an int reference key the geCustomer should

1. Execute e query on db customer table to retreive the correct customer based on the id
2. Build a Customer object filling its fields
3. REturn the object

So the differences beetwen the two appracches:

The first build a complete Order object that contains also Customer object etc. When need to display something, you have all what you need.

Second approach build a light Order object. When need to display for example the data of the customer whe need to query the db (this is called lazy loading)

I suggest you to consider using an ORM wich really helps you mapping OO design on DB and helps you build queries that return directly objects instead of "ids"

Comment: I used the Builder pattern for the Book, Customer, and Order classes because in any other case each object instance results in a new Connection to the database. By using the Builder pattern the objects are built in the SwingWorker threads and the data retrieval process uses a single Connection. In the first approach all the loading overhead falls upon the OrdersDataLoader thread. Since each object instance uses a different Connection, 100 order would result in 300 connection! I think the same stands for the second approach.
I would like to see a more efficient and extensible solution.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to have a persistent connection so you don't ahve to open a connection each time you build an object? Otherwise i suggest to execute a single query with joins all tables (orders, customer, books etc) on the foreing keys. Then adapt your builder to use the result of a such a query instead of directly querying the database

Comment: The DAO pattern (as @bennidi mentioned) would be a solution for the persistent connection I think, however there is still a big number of queries generated. The joined queries solution is worth noticing but it seems to lead in data duplication.